# The Java SDK access client failed to start due to a compatibility issue with a third-party dependency (spring-tx)

Tags: java, spring, sdk

I am maintaining a **Java SDK** that, due to historical reasons, has integrated many third-party dependencies, including common ones such as Spring and gRPC.

The current Spring Boot version on the client is 2.5.14, and I plan to integrate the SDK into the client. The client's Spring Boot version can run normally on versions 2.2.0.RELEASE to 2.7.14, but cannot start on versions 2.1.18.RELEASE and below (2.0.0.RELEASE to 2.1.18.RELEASE). The corresponding incompatible Spring versions are those below 5.2.

The error message is as follows:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gtxsTransactionAspectSupport': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.netease.cloud.gtxs.core.rm.transaction.GtxsTransactionAspectSupport] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:262) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1198) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:513) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:484) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:618) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:177) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:318) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.netease.cloud.gtxs.core.rm.transaction.GtxsTransactionAspectSupport] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:659) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:556) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:541) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:245) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/TransactionManager
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2729) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2003) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:641) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

I found that the SDK uses Spring's transactional functionality and inherits the `TransactionAspectSupport` class (`org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport`). `TransactionAspectSupport` contains a member object `transactionManager`, which is an abstract interface added in Spring 5.2. Previous versions did not have this member and instead had a member of type `PlatformTransactionManager`. This is consistent with the client integration error message, leading me to suspect that this might be the cause of the compatibility issue. However, the SDK code does not directly reference `TransactionManager`, and even when I configure the `spring-tx` dependency as 'provided', the error still occurs. This is very confusing to me. What could be the root cause of this issue?

[TransactionManager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6Yty.png)

I attempted to resolve this issue by setting the spring-tx dependency of the SDK to 'provided', with the aim of using the client's Spring-tx. However, the error remains the same.

Comment: The problem is probably that you're depending on outdated library versions while other parts expect newer versions, so classes were added or removed, and you have a mismatch on your classpath, resulting in the error.